# <true> expected to be != to <true>. test failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My test is the following:

```
test "should post make_admin" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, admin: true)
    sign_in(user)
    before_value = user.admin
    post :make_admin, id: user.id
    after_value = user.admin
    assert_not_equal before_value, after_value
    assert_response :redirect
  end
```

and the controller looks like this:

```
def make_admin
    user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    user.toggle!(:admin)
    redirect_to static_pages_user_index_path
  end
```

and yet I keep getting this error:

```
Failure:
test_should_post_make_admin(StaticPagesControllerTest) [..../functional/static_pages_controller_test.rb:48]:
<true> expected to be != to
<true>.
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated, but why is `toggle_admin` called `make_admin`? You don't actually have both a `make_admin` and `unmake_admin` or something, do you?

Comment: @DaveNewton No, I don't. You're right, it's a bad name. It does the same thing. The reason it is called that is 99% of the time you will make the person an admin.

Comment: don't understand the -1 neither...

Comment: @apneadiving I was at -4 at one point! If I deserved it, I would have wanted a chance to revise the question and make it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd replace:

```
after_value = user.admin
```

with:

```
after_value = user.reload.admin
```

Comment: Why is this necessary? It fixed it, but I'm not sure why I need to reload.

Comment: because the object in memory remains the same if you don't tell it to refresh. And hopefuly, it would be a perf killer otherwise